C# Winforms Panel ScrollBar Jumping when focus changes
I have come across a couple similar questions however the solutions posted did not work for my case.
Some detail:
I am creating a Dashboard, I have a Main Content Panel (Scrollable) that is populated with a UserControl based on the page selected.
On the user control I have multiple different graphs and tables for dashboarding purposes.
I have a custom tool tip that appears next to the cursor when hovering. It works perfectly until I click on any of the graphs. Then the whenever the tool tip is moved to the cursor position the scroll bar jumps to a seemingly random position near the top of the UserControl.
I was able to conclude the jumping occurs during the tool tip moving process:
Tool Tip Code:
 private void ytdSalesChart_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
 {

     Chart control = sender as Chart;

     Panel parent = this.Parent as Panel;

     int ScrollPosStart = parent.VerticalScroll.Value;

     Debug.WriteLine($"Moving Tooltip! Scroll Pos: {ScrollPosStart}");
     if (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
     {
         int i = e.HitTestResult.PointIndex;
         int seriesI = control.Series.IndexOf(e.HitTestResult.Series);
         DataPoint dp = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[i];

         if (!chartTip.Visible)
         {
             chartTip.Visible = true;
         }
         chartTip.SetTitle(e.HitTestResult.Series.Name.Trim());
         chartTip.SetValLbl("Value: " + FormatNumber(dp.YValues[0]));
         chartTip.SetSeries("Branch: " + dp.AxisLabel);

         chartTip.SetSeriesColor(control.PaletteCustomColors[seriesI]);
         chartTip.Location = new Point(control.Parent.Location.X + e.X + 10, control.Parent.Location.Y + e.Y + 10);
         chartTip.BringToFront();
         Debug.WriteLine($"Finished Moving Tooltip! Scroll Pos: {parent.VerticalScroll.Value}");
         parent.VerticalScroll.Value = ScrollPosStart;
         this.ActiveControl = null; This helped but did not fix the issue also added to the on_click for the charts (helped more cases)
     }
     else
     {
         chartTip.Visible = false;
     }

 }

The output I get when the bug is occurring is (Keep in mind this is spamming my console for testing and all occurs in a fraction of a second when I hover the chart for the tool tip):
It does different things depending on conditions:
When I am scrolled to the top (0) it does the below
Moving Tooltip! Scroll Pos: 0
Finished Moving Tooltip! Scroll Pos: 194
Moving Tooltip! Scroll Pos: 87 

The third line is the second run of the ytdSalesChart_GetToolTipText because the scroll bug triggers again from the the moving where the mouse is touching.
Any information/insight on what is going on will be helpful.
---UPDATE---
After some testing and adjusting I have found that changing the form from Fullscreen to Windowed and back again will stop the bug.
As @Jimi commented it is not a bug but more of an unintended consequence of default behavior.
I am still unclear on how to avoid this behavior but I suspect looking into how the focus changes when interacting with maximize button / a component outside of the User Control (Panel) will lead to a solution.
If I figure it out I will post my fix thanks for reading.
-- SOLVED --
Thanks to @Jimi pointed me in the right direction (comments)



See whether the notes here can help you make sense of the issue (as it appears, not actually an issue - or a bug - just default behavior): Why does my FlowLayoutPanel automatically scroll back to the top when the form loses and regains focus?

The fix is to change whatever Panel you are using as the scrolling panel to a custom UserControl and override the ScrollToControl function.
As stated in the other posts @Jimi commented, it is a "Feature" that will scroll to the active control. To get around this you can use this code below and for your container instead...
internal class CustomFlowLayoutPanel : System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
{
    protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control activeControl)
    {
        // Returning the current location prevents the panel from
        // scrolling to the active control when the panel loses and regains focus
        return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
    }
}

